# how to create a new activity template in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to create a new activity template to save time when I add an activity to my android studios project.
I have essentially cloned the code for basic activity as I want the following to be true:

- split activity/content layout files.
- inclusion of toolbar code
- inclusion of my own java code template

which have been achieved, however, I cannot figure out how to achieve either of these:

- how to NOT include the floating action button (i have removed the java lines relating to it, but cannot find anywhere in the XML generation files that it is added to the layout?)
- how to auto-generate the creation date (it does not like the use of ${YEAR} etc in my comment block. I'm attempting a six-digit date format: YYMMDD?)

I've followed numerous online guides and still cannot find how to accomplish this. any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

About the removal of FloatingActionButton. It is declared inside

```
templates/activities/common/root/res/layout/app_bar.xml.ftl
```

Inside the Basic Activity template it is called from

```
templates/activities/BasicActivity/recipe.xml.ftl
```

Which in turn calls

```
templates/activities/common/recipe_app_bar.xml.ftl
```

In order to remove the button; I would copy the recipe_app_bar.xml.ftl(because it has other declarations; not only the FloatingActionButton) into my template and call it; removing the call to app_bar.xml.ftl

Comment: thanks. could you please explain/show how to do this? as i am looking at the recipie file and see the call to recipie_app_bar, not a call to app_bar? looking at recepie_app_bar it instantiates from root/res/layout/app_bar.xml.ftl? did you mean for me to copy THIS file and edit it?

Comment: recipe_app_bar.xml.ftl calls app_bar.xml.ftl. Both of these files are inside the common folder,  so they are used by other templates too. You should not edit those. I suggest you replicate the logic of both recipe_app_bar.xml.ftl and app_bar.xml.ftl (without the fab) inside your template and call your copy instead.